# how do i convert int to byte and back

Tags: lua

given a 64bit int I need to split it into 4 x 2bytes int.

for example decimal 66309 is `0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0011 0000 0101`

I need to convert this into an array of 4 ints `{0, 1, 3, 5}`. How can I do it in lua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the conversion of 66309 into four 16 bit integers wouldn't be `{0, 1, 3, 5}`, but `{0, 0, 1, 773}`. In your example, you are splitting it into 8 bit integers. The below does 16 bit integers.

```
local int = 66309
local t = {}
for i = 0, 3 do
    t[i+1] = (int >> (i * 16)) & 0xFFFF
end
```

If you want it to be 8 bit integers change the `3` in the loop to `7`, the `16` in the shift expression to an `8`, and the hex mask `0xFFFF` to `0xFF`.

And finally, this only works for Lua 5.3. You cannot accurately represent a 64 bit integer in Lua before this version without external libraries.

Comment: you are right. 1byte = 8 bit. I messed up and thought 1byte = 4 bit